# Using indexies of min

Tags: indexing, octave, min

My problem is that I have done some distance calculation of points in a picture to three static points. I want to know which of the distances is the smallest and write the value of the pixel to a second array. I used `min()` to get the indices, but I don't know how to access the picture with those. I simplified the code a little:

```
data = rand(5, 5, 3);          # distances of a 5x5 image to 3 different points
[~, mi] = min(data, [], 3);    # which of the distances is the minimum
result = picture(mi);          # write pixel values to result
```

I know this would only give me the values of `picture(1:3, 1, 1)`, so the first three pixels, and I didn't found a suited function to convert the indicies. How can I achieve this and avoid writing a loop?

**Edit**

For clearification. `mi` may be

```
data = rand(3, 3, 2)
data = 
ans(:, :, 1) = 
    0.316498   0.054937   0.606390
    0.537073   0.231184   0.790371
    0.770788   0.334282   0.522369

ans(:,:,2) =
   0.843369   0.051667   0.227570  
   0.452298   0.407662   0.648079
   0.450546   0.398068   0.281694

[~, mi] = min(data, [], 3)
mi =
   1   2   2
   2   1   2
   2   1   2

data(mi)
ans =
   0.31650   0.53707   0.53707
   0.53707   0.31650   0.53707
   0.53707   0.31650   0.53707
```

As you can see, I access with those indecies only `data(1)` and `data(2)` which is basically `data(1, 1, 1)` and `data(2, 1, 1)`, but I'd like to have the following result

```
0.31650    0.051667   0.227570  
0.452298   0.231184   0.648079
0.450546   0.334282   0.281694
```

Comment: Convert the indices to what? You're already addressing the picture with them...

Comment: Yes, but not as I would expect. I expanded my question.

Comment: mmm... any reason you're not using the *first* output from `min`? What am I missing?

Comment: I want to access the original picture with those indices. `result = picture(mi);          # write pixel values to result`

Comment: `result = min(data, [], 3)` doesn't give you that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return of [`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) in this context is giving you the slice of your matrix where the minimum occurs, which is the expected result but not necessarily the most useful one. You can use [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) with [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to generate [linear indices](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) to access the locations of your minimums:

```
tmp = rand(3, 3, 2);
[mins, mi] = min(tmp, [], 3);

[r, c, ~] = size(tmp);  % Get number of rows & columns
[y, x] = meshgrid(1:r, 1:c);  % Generate x,y pairs
lidx = sub2ind(size(tmp), x(:), y(:), mi(:));  % Generate linear indices

% Test out the linear indices
mins_lidx = reshape(tmp(lidx), r, c);  % Reshape to the slice size
```

Where

```
>> all(mins(:)==mins_lidx(:))

ans =

  logical

   1
```

You can also just use the subscripts `[x(:), y(:), mi(:)]` if desired, but it seems more unwieldy in this context.